# Can you use transition().delay() and .classed() together?

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to check and apply classes during a transition, with a delay. I'm finding that it's not possible.

Some code I've tried:

```
 citycircles = instamap.append("g")
        .selectAll(".city-circles")
          .data(points.features)
          .enter()
            .append("circle");

citycircles.transition().duration().delay(500)
       .classed("cities-selected", function(d,i) {
            if (i === nearestcircle) return true;
        });

d3.selectAll(".city-circles").transition().duration().delay(500)
      .classed("cities-selected", function(d,i) {
              if (i === nearestcircle) return true;
      });
```

Comment: Transitions don't support classed as yet so you need to find another way I'm afraid...

Comment: In particular, D3 will not look up the CSS values defined for a class and interpolate from the previous ones -- you need to set the attribute/style values you want to interpolate explicitly.

Comment: It seems like using .each() with a delay and then .classed() within .each() is the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's [the man himself](https://twitter.com/mbostock/status/653967728747769856) on the topic:

```
No plans on supporting that at the moment; to transition classes, native CSS transitions are typically sufficient.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setTimeout` instead

```
citycircles = instamap.append("g")
    .selectAll(".city-circles")
    .data(points.features).enter()
    .append("circle");

setTimeout(function() {

    citycircles.classed("cities-selected",function(d,i) {
        if (i === nearestcircle) {
            return true
        }
    });

    d3.selectAll(".city-circles").classed("cities-selected",function(d,i) {
       if (i === nearestcircle) {
           return true
       }
   });

}, 500);
```

Comment: Don't know why this was downvoted. It helped me. Thanks!